# trying to create a single hover event for multiple wrappers

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#photo1").hover(function conton() {
  if($(this).hasClass("containerz")) {
    $("#container").addClass("hovercont");
    $("#title").addClass("hovertitle");
    $("#photo1").addClass("hoverwrapper");
  }
}, function contoff() {
  $("#container").removeClass("hovercont");
  $("#photo1").removeClass("hoverwrapper");
  $("#title").removeClass("hovertitle");
  tornaback();
})
```

hi, i have created many identical containers for photos that when hovered over apply classes with specific animations to the photo itself and to the title that are inside. This code works well on a single container, but i'm having problems translating it in a way that allows me to apply it to many different containers without having to copy and paste it for every new container i create. thanks for the help

in these lines of code, #photo1 is the main wrapper and #container is a div inside #photo1 with the photo inside

Comment: Why dont you use css `:hover` [selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) instead of javascript. Then you can just apply classes to the container/photo/title and then you dont have to use js

Comment: If I understand correctly there are a lot of `#photo` divs? Like `#photo1`, `#photo2` etc.? And in every one of them there is a div `#container`?

Comment: This could all be achieved with just CSS, so long as there's a common parent that you can apply the :hover to and target the children that way.

Comment: Additionally it sounds like you're repeating ID's, these should be unique - consider using a class for something for which there are many instances of. It may help to see the HTML code that you're trying to work with.

Comment: well having hardcoded ids like title and container looks like it would be hard to make it reusable and not seeing the html markup makes it hard to give a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all** you should not have more than one element with the same id. So maybe change `id` to `class`

**Secondly** it is better to do it in css (since it is possible). It is faster and more proper way to go.

**Here is an example**

```css
[id^="photo"] {
  display: inline-block;
}

.title {
  color: blue;
}
[id^="photo"]:hover .title {
  color: red;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100px;
}
[id^="photo"]:hover .container {
  max-width: 150px;
}
.container img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="photo1">
  <div class="title">Title 1</div>
  <div class="container"><img src="https://proxy.topixcdn.com/ipicimg/1N8II1A857Q5NONT-cp0x134x1600x932-fill810x415x" /></div>
</div>
<div id="photo2">
  <div class="title">Title 2</div>
  <div class="container"><img src="https://proxy.topixcdn.com/ipicimg/1N8II1A857Q5NONT-cp0x134x1600x932-fill810x415x" /></div>
</div>
<div id="photo3">
  <div class="title">Title 3</div>
  <div class="container"><img src="https://proxy.topixcdn.com/ipicimg/1N8II1A857Q5NONT-cp0x134x1600x932-fill810x415x" /></div>
</div>
<div id="photo4">
  <div class="title">Title 4</div>
  <div class="container"><img src="https://proxy.topixcdn.com/ipicimg/1N8II1A857Q5NONT-cp0x134x1600x932-fill810x415x" /></div>
</div>
<div id="photo5">
  <div class="title">Title 5</div>
  <div class="container"><img src="https://proxy.topixcdn.com/ipicimg/1N8II1A857Q5NONT-cp0x134x1600x932-fill810x415x" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i'm already using different id's like photo1, 2 etc.., so using the :hover like you did here i just have to make a :hover for every id and copy/paste it right?

Comment: No, here is an example of many ids like photo1, 2 etc... And I did not copy anything.